# Exclusive access to the microphone in Android

Tags: android, security, microphone

Is it possible to get exclusive access to Android microphone from an application ?

I am trying to extend CSipSimple application and my goal is to improve it's security.
One of the goals, which I have no idea how to approach, is to block other applications to record my conversations.

I have downloaded an app from PlayStore, Call Recorder it's called, and it gets automatically on when I dial a phone number and it is recording my phone conversation.
That is what I need to avoid.

So, can I stop any application from recording my voice while I am on call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about android, but if gaining exclusive access to the mic is not possible, one path you can tread is monitor apps with mic permissions, if they exist, and close them using root. Or when your app is running, you could remove the broadcast listeners of such apps, like some autorun managers do.

Comment: Hi. Thank for your answer. I need to investigate if Android is that permissive in order to monitor apps which have access to mic and also close them. I have to do some research here. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for the late rating. It all came from your indications

Comment: ... this answer has the green check? XD

Answer (score 4):

As Harsha C Alva mentioned, one way of doing this is to iterate installed applications, check their permissions and kill them if they are running.

In order to iterate install apps

```
private void iterateInstalledApps()
{
    PackageManager p = this.getPackageManager();
    final List <PackageInfo> appinstall = 
        p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    for(PackageInfo pInfo:appinstall)
    {
        String[] reqPermission=pInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if(reqPermission!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<reqPermission.length;i++)
            {
                if (((String)reqPermission[i]).equals("android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"))
                {
                    killPackage(pInfo.packageName.toString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

In order to kill one package

```
private void killPackage(String packageToKill)
{
    ActivityManager actvityManager = 
        (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    final List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = 
        actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : procInfos) 
    {
        if(runningAppProcessInfo.processName.equals(packageToKill)) 
        {
            android.os.Process.sendSignal(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, 
                                android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
            actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageToKill);
        }           
    }       
}
```

You can call iterateInstalledApps in a timer because Android is restarting the app on the spot. If you keep killing the application it will not manage to record anything. Testing with Call Recorder while speaking on the phone.

Comment: Looks like very dirty hack :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing about android is that you don't have access to the hardware directly in your app (native or not) android implements servers for the hardware that manages it and your app connects to them and get what those servers are providing.

There is a great video from android guys describing this model in the media framework case. [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0UmSQeWsJc) is the link to it.

So no you can't enfoce access limitations in this model, with that being said the other answers represents a reasonable way to make sure the microphone is not being accessed by others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can *only* get exclusive access to the microphone. If I try to use two `AudioRecord`s concurrently I get this error:

```
E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
```

This is literally the only information I have found on the topic anywhere on the internet:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/d7iQm0pyiC0

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61643